# LIMIT SQL within WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to put a limit within a WHERE clause in sql?

Table name: `_mct_dot`

Columns: `a_ID (auto inc)    number (index)    qty (index)   com_val`

```
SELECT
        *
    FROM
        _mct_dot
    WHERE
        (
            number = 4
            OR
            number = 7
            OR
            number = 13
        )
        AND 
        (
            qty = 3
            OR
            qty = 5
            OR
            qty = 7
        )
    ORDER BY
        number ASC, qty ASC
```

So the above query, it will essentially return an array grouped in order. However it will pull out all of the 'qty' of values 3, 5 and 7. What I need is a sample of 5 results from 'qty' 3, 5 and 7. Ie. I need the results to look like:

```
'number' 4's with 'qty' = 3's where 'qty' limited to max 5 
'number' 4's with 'qty' = 5's where 'qty' limited to max 5 
'number' 4's with 'qty' = 7's where 'qty' limited to max 5 
'number' 7's with 'qty' = 3's where 'qty' limited to max 5 
'number' 7's with 'qty' = 5's where 'qty' limited to max 5 
'number' 7's with 'qty' = 7's where 'qty' limited to max 5 
'number' 13's with 'qty' = 3's where 'qty' limited to max 5 
'number' 13's with 'qty' = 5's where 'qty' limited to max 5 
'number' 13's with 'qty' = 7's where 'qty' limited to max 5
```

Comment: Could you post the DDL and data set to clarify this a bit more? Also having the desired results in actual form would help, unless the strings you have in the question are exactly that.

Comment: Please provide more information like an example of data in the tables and the kind of output you expect from the query. That would help us in understanding the question better!!

Comment: Don't know about MySQL but in Sql Server you can achieve this (kind of) by using the `row_number() over (partition by )` function. Eg:

`select * 
from
( 
select 
  number
, qty
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY number order by attribute_number, grade_number asc) as RN
from _mct_dot
) a
where a.RN<6
order by 1,3 asc`

Comment: Thanks Sergiu, I am stuck with mysql on this one though.

Comment: I have updated the post, hopefully is clearer. Although i am sesning that this is not really possible with mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to add a `LIMIT` clause within a WHERE clause.

It is possible to achieve the resultset you want, but the SQL to do that isn't pretty. It's going to require either a JOIN, a correlated subquery, or an inline view.

---

If there's an "order" to the rows in _mct_dot, you could use a correlated subquery to check for the number of rows "before" the row you pulled, and take rows only that have fewer than four rows.

```
SELECT d.*
  FROM _mct_dot d
  JOIN ( SELECT n.number
              , q.qty
           FROM (SELECT 4 AS `number` UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 13) n
          CROSS
           JOIN (SELECT 3 AS `qty` UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 7) q
       ) p
    ON p.number = d.number
   AND p.qty = d.qty
   AND 5 > ( SELECT SUM(1)
               FROM _mct_dot c
              WHERE c.number = d.number
                AND c.qty = d.qty
                AND c.a_ID < d.a_ID
           )
 ORDER BY ...
```

The correlated subquery could wind up being executed a LOT of times, so for best performance, you are going to want an index with leading columns of `number` and `qty` and including the `a_id` column.

Either:

```
... ON `_mct_dot` (`number`, `qty`, `a_ID`)
```

or

```
... ON `_mct_dot` (`qty`, `number`, `a_ID`)
```

---

Another option is to use MySQL user variables, to emulate a `row_number()` analytic function, something like this:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM ( SELECT d.a_ID
              , IF(d.number = @prev_number AND d.qty = @prev_qty
                  , @rn := @rn + 1
                  , @rn := 1
                ) AS rn
              , @prev_number := d.number
              , @prev_qty := d.qty
           FROM (SELECT @prev_number := NULL, @prev_qty := NULL, @rn := 0 ) i
          CROSS 
           JOIN ( SELECT n.number
                       , q.qty
                    FROM (SELECT 4 AS `number` UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 13) n
                   CROSS
                    JOIN (SELECT 3 AS `qty` UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 7) q
                ) p
           JOIN _mct_dot d
             ON d.number = p.number
            AND d.qty = p.qty
          ORDER BY d.number, d.qty
       ) s
  JOIN _mct_dot t
    ON t.a_ID = s.a_ID
 WHERE s.rn <= 5 
 ORDER BY t.number ASC, t.qty ASC
```

(These queries are desk checked only; haven't setup a SQL Fiddle demo.)

**FOLLOWUP**

For the first query, I've just used an inline view (aliased as "p"), that generates the set of all pairs of `number` and `qty` values that are being requested.

And we can use a JOIN operation to locate all the rows that match each pair from _mct_dot table.

The tricky part is the correlated subquery. (There's a couple of approaches we could use.) The approach in the query above is to get a "count" of the rows with a matching "number" and "qty", but with an id value less than the id value of the current row, basically finding out how many rows are "before" the current row. And we're comparing that to a literal 5, because we want to return only the first 5 rows in each group.

---

For the second query,

the inline view aliased as **`i`** is initializing some MySQL user variables. We don't really care what's returned by the query, except that it returns exactly one row (because we're referencing it in a JOIN operation)... what we're really interested in is getting the variables initialized at the start of the execution. And that happens because MySQL materializes the inline view (derived table), before the outer query that references the view is executed.

The inline view aliased as **`p`** gets us the pairs of `number,qty` that we want to retrieve, and we use a JOIN operation against _mct_dot to get the matching rows.

The "trick" in the inline view aliased as **`s`** is the use of the MySQL user variables. We're doing a check of the current values against the values from the previous row... if the number and qty match, then we're in the same "group", so we can increment the row number counter by 1. If either of the values change, then it's a new group, so we reset the row number counter to 1, since the current row is the "first" row in the new group.

We can run the query for the inline view **`s`**, and see that we're getting row numbers (`rn` col) 1, 2, 3, etc. for each group.

Then the outermost query just filters out all the rows that have an `rn` row number greater than five. Actually, from **`s`**, we're returning just the unique identifier for the row; that outermost query is also doing a JOIN operation to retrieve the entire row, based on the unique id.

---

As I mentioned at the top of my answer, the SQL to do this is not pretty. (It does take a bit of work to unwind what those queries are doing.)

Comment: Wow! OK, my knowledge on sql has just been seriously dwarfed! Thank you for the detailed answer. It is going to take a little bit of time to fully understand your solution.

Comment: @John: the short answer is that you can't use a LIMIT clause within a WHERE clause. The longer answer is that it is possible to achieve the resultset, but the queries to do require some work (on the part of the reader) to unwind and decipher what the queries are doing.) I added a FOLLOWUP with some brief notes to help explain each query.

Comment: @John: another note about that second query with the `@prev_` user variables: this uses a MySQL specific extension to SQL (not supported in other database), and (most importantly) the behavior we observe of user variables _within_ a SQL statement (like the example I gave) is _NOT_ guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly as it's not very clear, but based on what I've understood I think you can try something like this:

```
SELECT     attribute_number,
           grade_number //, other columns

FROM       _mct_dot
WHERE      (number = 4 AND qty IN (3, 5 ,7))
OR         (number = 7 AND qty IN (3, 5, 7))
OR         (number = 13 AND qty IN (3, 5, 7))
GROUP BY   attribute_number, grade_number
ORDER BY   attribute_number ASC, grade_number ASC
LIMIT      5
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: thanks, but this did not work, top 5 caused an error.

Comment: Updated the query!! Please check if this works for you!!

Comment: But wouldn't this just be a global limit of 5. As in, it would only ever return a max of 5 results overall instead of (3x5)x3 - ie 45.